# How to clone an SVG Map Using xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I need to copy the svg map come from other website.

Here is the website for example where i'm going to copy the svg map: 
`https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com`

Here is the xpath location from the website:
`//*[@id="visitsMap"]`

What I need?
I'd like to copy the result/post of that `xpath` into my page.

Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("svg").clone().appendTo("body");
    });

$svgTemplate = new SimpleXMLElement($svg_data);
$svgTemplate->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com');

$style = $svgTemplate->xpath('//*[@id="visitsMap"]');
printf("Original style:\n%s\n\n", (string)$style[0]);

});
</script>

</head>
  <body>
 
        <svg></svg>

  </body>
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to read the Alexa T&Cs, as well as read up on intellectual property, copyright infringement, etc. But back to the technical issue, you are going to face an issue with cross-origin requests. So you’ll have to go through a server to fetch the information.

Comment: This for e.g only...! but im not going to use alexa. for it... :) some advice me just to use iframe...

Comment: You can indeed use an iframe, but you won't be able to style it, manipulate it, add event handlers to different parts of the map, etc. It'll just be a "black box".

Comment: correct... thats why i need some bet soln...in it

Comment: Well, that map is actually drawn by amCharts, so you're probably better off calling amCharts yourself and just get the original data from the Alexa page (search for `ALEXA.viewsHelpers.map.areas` in that page to find the data). But as cross-origin requests are not allowed for that page, you'll need to go through a server to get that data into your page.

Comment: So the only way to gopy that if they provide some kind of access eg api...something??\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uSING AMCHARTS..

```html
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {

  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "projection": "mercator",

"dataProvider": {
  "map": "worldLow",
  "areas": [
    { "id": "US" } //BY CHANGING THIS<--
 
  ]
},
  
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"
  },

} );
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**To View a Demo:** http://webbatlas.com/google.com